# Why does this give output as 1 2 6 24 and not 24 6 2 1

Tags: python

```
def recurr(k):  
       if (k>0):
           result =k*recurr(k-1)
           print(result)
       else:
           result=1
       return result 
recurr(4)
```

Output :
1
2
6
24